# mongoDB aggregate $lookup and push some info from existing array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have many collections in my MongoDB database.
Aggregation work's good but I can't push some fields to the output I needed,

collection A is:

```
{
  _id: some mongodbID
  //...fields
  items: [
   {
     _id: someId,
     color: someId <---- Im aggregate this with lookup
     neededFieldToPush: 123
   },
   {
     _id: someId,
     color: someId <---- Im aggregate this with lookup
     neededFieldToPush: 566
   }
  ]
}
```

my query is:

```
await Invoice.aggregate([
  { $match: query },
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  //colors
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colors",
      localField: "items.itemColor",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "itemColor"
    }
   },
   {
     $addFields: {
       "prMove.itemColor": { $arrayElemAt: ["$itemColor.colorName", 0] },
     }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        items: { $push: "$items" }, <-- original items
        prMove: { $push: "$prMove" },
       }
     },
   ])
   .sort({date: -1})
   .skip(+req.query.offset)
   .limit(+req.query.limit)
```

I need to have output like this:

```
_id: someId,
items: [//original items],
prMove: [
  {
    itemColor: some color name, <--- it's works fine
    neededFieldToPush: 123
  },
  {
    itemColor: some color name, <--- it's works fine
    neededFieldToPush: 566
  },      
]
```

so, how I can push `neededFieldToPush` field into `prMove` object?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your query is expensive because you have used `$unwind` stage and `$group` stage, it will impact performance,

The second thing is the `$sort`, `$skip` and `$limit` functions will not work on the aggregate function of mongoose, you have use stages for that,

The third thing is to use sort, `$skip` and `$limit` stages immediately after `$match` stage, so it will improve performance while you create an index on required fields.

Improved query,

- `$match` your query
- `$sort` sort stage
- `$skip` stage to pass offset
- `$limit` stage to limit documents
- `$lookup` with colors collection and pass `items.color` as `localField`
- `$addFields` to edit `items` array with color name in `items`
- `$map` to iterate loop of `items` array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `itemColor` array result from lookup, check condition if `_id` match then get color name and set value in `color` field
- `$mergeObjects` to merge new `color` field and current fields of the item object
- `$$REMOVE` to remove `itemColor` array because it is not needed now

```
let offset = req.query.offset;
let limit = req.query.limit;
await Invoice.aggregate([
  { $match: query },
  { $sort: { date: -1 } },
  { $skip: offset },
  { $limit: limit },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "colors",
      localField: "items.color",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "itemColor"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$i",
              {
                color: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$itemColor",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$i._id"] },
                        "$$this.colorName",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      itemColor: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ikw2LYGURAg)